# inserting productcode from msi into powershell script - running into issues with null-values

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, powershell-3.0, sccm

I'm writing an automated solution for a product that we package into SCCM 2012 monthly and am having some difficulty with parsing the GUID of the *.msi file into a variable to be used in my detection method script.

No matter how I come at it, I either end up with a space at the front of the variable which breaks my detection script, or a null-value error if I try and modify the variable that holds the msi guid result.

Code snippet below with the errors that I get.

--

```
$FILE           =   "$APPLOCATION\$APPNAME.MSI"

#Function to pull the GUID from the Msi
#------------
function global:Get-MsiProductCode {
param(
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[IO.FileInfo]$Path,
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateSet("ProductCode","ProductVersion","ProductName")]
[string]$Property
)
try {
    $WindowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
    $MSIDatabase = $WindowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase","InvokeMethod",$Null,$WindowsInstaller,@($Path.FullName,0))
    $Query = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = '$Property'"
    $View = $MSIDatabase.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView","InvokeMethod",$null,$MSIDatabase,($Query))
    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null)
    $Record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch","InvokeMethod",$null,$View,$null)
    $Value = $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData","GetProperty",$null,$Record,1)
    return $Value
} 
catch {
    Write-Output $_.trim().replace(' ','')
}
}
#-------------
$MSICode =(Get-MsiProductCode -Path $File -Property ProductCode)
$testoutput = "Here is a test of the msicode.$msicode"
$SCRIPTDETECT   =   @"
if (gwmi -Query "select * from win32_Product where IdentifyingNumber='$MSICODE'") {
    if (gwmi -Query "select * from EthIL where $APPNAME`Version='$ENVIRO'") {write-host "Installed"}
    else{
        if (gwmi -Query "select * from EthIL where $APPNAME`64Version='$ENVIRO'") {write-host "Installed"}
        else {}
        }
}
else{}
"@

write-output $msicode
write-output $SCRIPTDETECT
write-host $testoutput
```

--

the output to the above code looks as follows

```
{713335BD-14AB-460D-92C1-196DBE000D73}
if (gwmi -Query "select * from win32_Product where IdentifyingNumber=' {713335BD-14AB-460D-92C1-196DBE000D73}'") {
    if (gwmi -Query "select * from EthIL where EthILVersion='SDPRODCOPY'") {write-host "Installed"}
    else{
        if (gwmi -Query "select * from EthIL where EthIL64Version='SDPRODCOPY'") {write-host "Installed"}
        else {}
        }
}
else{}
here is a test of the msicode. {713335BD-14AB-460D-92C1-196DBE000D73}
```

--

so as you can see the first echo of msicode brings back the GUID without a space. the use of $MSICODE as part of a string adds a space to the string before $MSICODE is called.

If I try and modify $MSICODE to perhaps trim the spaces or replace the spaces with the below code

```
$msicode = $msicode.replace(' ','')
```

I get the following error

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:45 char:1
+ $msicode = $msicode.replace(' ','')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

--

Please help!! I'm so lost with the null-value, but my brain just can't comprehend why a space is being place before the value when there isn't one in the output!!!

**UPDATE**
I have found a way to get the result I am after using psmsi using the below code.

```
$msicode = get-msitable $File -table Property | where-object { $_.Property -eq "ProductCode" } | select-object -expand Value
```

This has now resolved my issue, however I am still curious as to why my function performs as it does.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Windows Installer PowerShell Module](https://psmsi.codeplex.com/) to get this info instead?

Comment: Hi Mike, yes I have tried using psmsi however i haven't had any success retrieving the correct GUID. it retrieves the packagecode but not the productcode - two very different GUIDs. If there is a way to use psmsi to retrieve the productcode, I'd be very happy to utilise that - however, the code above does the same thing, so I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong!!

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the difference between a product code and package code but I don't see why `Get-MSITable -Path $Path.FullName -Query "SELECT Value FROM Property Where Property = 'ProductCode'" | foreach { Get-MSIProductInfo -ProductCode $_.Value }` isn't what you are trying to do. It's also going to be a lot faster than querying Win32_Product.

Comment: Just a few seconds faster than me! Anyway, you are calling trim on the exception object in `Get-MsiProductCode`. Don't you want to call Trim on `$Value`? I didn't see a space in the one msi I tried, so this is a guess, but it could be a BOM or some encoding problem. Best bet would be to dump the raw bytes: `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($msicode) -join " "` and see what is at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @mikez I tried calling trim on a million different areas. But yes  I try trimming $Value. the issue was that $msicode didnt return with a space at the front until it was put into the middle of something else... very strange.
How would I use that code you mentioned?